# Why isn't this working - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project to check to see if a new items is updated on a website. I want to the program to check every second to see if a new item has come in. The items are designated by an ID (which I can get). However, I am having trouble using AJAX to update the part of the website. I want it to 'refresh' the website every second and compare the most recent item to its previous most recent item (i.e. if current > past). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick = "body()">Click Me</button>

<script>
var highest = 0;
var compare = 0;
var creator;
var newItem = false;
var HelpPeople = 'People's Names';

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-itmhover');

highest = elements[0].getElementsByClassName('ms-vb2')[1].innerText;

 var body = function()
{
        window.setTimeout(update(), 1000);
}

var update = function()
{
    window.jquery-2('body').load('URL');

    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-itmhover');

    compare = elements[0].getElementsByClassName('ms-vb2')[1].innerText;

    creator = elements[0].getElementsByClassName('ms-vb-user')[0].innerText;

    if(compare > highest && creaCompare(creator))
    {
        displayNew();
    }

    body();
}

var creaCompare = function(create)
{
    var comparer = false;

    for(var i = 0; i < HelpPeople.length; i++)
    {
        if(create == HelpPeople[i])
        {
            comparer = true;
        }
    }
    return comparer;
}

var displayNew = function()
{

    confirm('There is a new item');
    body();

}
</script>
</body>
```

I think I asked the question wrong. I am looking to run this on a website (not my own) and have it parse out data and check for new items (AJAX). I am wondering how to use it and how I can use JS on this website (can I run it through the console?)

Comment: Your jQuery import looks wrong unless you have it in a file called jquery-2.1.1.js

Comment: start by checking browser console for errors such as from `jquery-2('body')`

Comment: `jquery-2` is not a valid variable name, you're saying `jquery` (which will be either a function or undefined) minus two. Which is `NaN`

Comment: `setTimeout` expects a function, you're calling it on `update()` which doesn't return anything. I think you mean `setTimeout(update, 1000);`

Comment: next time put your code into an online syntax checker first before posting it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code because you're using jQuery... but not using it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btnTest">Click Me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
// wait for document loaded
$(function () {

var updateUrl = 'put your update url here';

var highest = 0;
var compare = 0;
var creator;
var newItem = false;
var HelpPeople = 'People's Names';

var elements = $('.ms-itmhover');          // where's this element

highest = $('.ms-vb2', elements).text();   // where are those elements ????

var body = function () {
    $('#btnTest").prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
};

var update = function()
{
    $('body').load(updateUrl, function (response, status, xhr) {
        if ( status == "error" ) {
            alert("Sorry but there was an error : " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            return;
        }

        elements = $('.ms-itmhover');
        compare = $('.ms-vb2', elements).text();
        creator = $('.ms-vb-user', elements).text();

        if (compare > highest && creaCompare(creator))
        {
            displayNew();
        }

        body();
    });
};

var creaCompare = function(create) {
    var comparer = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < HelpPeople.length; i++)
    {
        if(create == HelpPeople[i]) {
            comparer = true;
        }
    }
    return comparer;
};

var displayNew = function() {
    confirm('There is a new item');
    body();
};

// prevent button click more than once
$('#btnTest").one('click', body);

});
</script>
</body>
```

As for answering the actual question, without more HTML, there's not much that can be answered. But the above change presumably fixes :

1. Executing JS code before document is loaded; now wait until page has loaded
2. Properly make use of jQuery's DOM traversal and manipulation functions.
3. Better HTML/JS separation
4. Encapsulate variables in "private" scope (prevent global namespace pollution) (thank you George Mauer)
5. You had invalid variable names (i.e. `jquery-2` is not what you expect, and `2(..)` is an invalid syntax)
6. Your had `setTimeout(update(), 1000);` which does nothing since it's essentially doing `setTimeout(undefined, 1000);`
7. You processed your updated HTML perhaps before it was even loaded (Ajax is async!)

What this answer does **not** cover :

1. What is the actual error (the question does not really specify)
2. Give a concrete working solution, since parts of the HTML is missing

Comment: As a bonus `$(...)` will also prevent all your variables from going global

Comment: This helps out with a few things however, I think I asked the question wrong. I am looking to run this on a website (not my own) and have it parse out data and check for new items (AJAX). I am wondering how to use it and how I can use JS on this website (can I run it through the console?)

Comment: If you use Chrome, sure! Just press F12 and go to the "Console" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably on this line:

```
window.jquery-2('body').load('URL');
```

It's not even a valid syntax. It should be written like this:

```
$('body').load('URL'); // Instead of 'URL' there also should be a proper URL
```

Also you should know the load function is asynchronous so if you need to do something with loaded elements, you need to put these actions in a callback. (A function passed as a second arguments of the load method.)